# C, calloc automatically takes care of overflow?

Tags: c

```
matrix* make_matrix(size_t width, size_t height, size_t k, options opt){

    matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(matrix));
    if(m==NULL) return NULL;

    m->width = width;
    m->height = height;
    m->k = k;

    /*
    Since m->data is a int **, it points to int *, 
    so I have to allocate a number of int *-sized objects to store in it.
    */
    //m->data = malloc(sizeof(int *)*height);
    m->data = calloc(height, sizeof(int*));

    if(m->data == NULL){
        free(m);
        return NULL;
    }

    for(size_t i=0; i < height; i++){
        //m->data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*width);
        m->data[i] = calloc(width, sizeof(int));

        if(m->data[i] == NULL){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) free(m->data[j]);
            free(m->data);
            free(m);
            return 0;
        }
        /*
        for(size_t j = 0; j < width; j++){
            m->data[i][j] = 0;
        }*/
    }

    return m;
}
```

I am generating an 2d array and I used malloc instead of calloc. And it turned out that this is going to be a sparse matrix where most of the elements will be zero. So I decided to use calloc. My question is that do I stil need to keep the if statement

```
        if(m->data[i] == NULL){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) free(m->data[j]);
            free(m->data);
            free(m);
            return 0;
        }
```

I wrote this because malloc doesn't take care of the stack over flow issue so in case of it fails then I have to free those blocks in reverse order. Do I still keep this code with calloc?

Comment: calloc == malloc + memset.

Comment: Yes, keep the code. You're not describing a sparse matrix though: for a 7x6 matrix with data in 12 cells, you're allocating space for 42 cells anyway (and setting those cells to 0).

Comment: could you tell me more about the sparse matrix? I am going to use a linked list but I am missing something.. What do you mean by 7x6 matrix with data in 12cells?

Comment: A linked list is a pretty hopeless data structure for a sparse matrix. Why on earth would you implement your own sparse matrix? You can use [CSparse](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html).

Comment: I was maybe getting a bit ahead. In the implementation of sparse matrixes, it is usual to not allocate space for the elements with 0. The 7x6 matrix example with only 12 values different than 0, would occupy memory for 12 values (and management) instead of 42. Imagine instead you have a 1000x1000 matrix of ints (4M) but only 100x100 cells (40K + management) are effectively needed. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `calloc` can (and will) fail just as hard as `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case of "stack overflow", as you are allocating objects on the heap.

The `if` is required for both `malloc` and `calloc`. What it does is that if you fail half-way through your allocation, it will delete the parts you already have allocated. The order is not important.